# In the code igniter loader function what file path does it want?

Tags: php, codeigniter, classloader

I am trying to load a flat text file into a controller.  I understand that I need to use the Loader function to do it (and set the second parameter to `true` to get a string back) but no matter what path I use, Loader cannot find the file.  Where is the top of the `file_path`?

`$this->load->file('../application/views/textiles/about.txt',true);`

It would also be nice to know how I set this loaded string to a variable to be passed to a view.

*Update*

I should add, that I just found something that works equally well as Jordan's solution for what I am attempting to do.  The text file is written in markdown and so to convert it for the view, you can also do the following (and worry less about the file path):

```
$this->load->helper('markdown');
$string = $this->load->view('text.txt', '', true);
$string = markdown($string);
$data['text'] = $string;
$this->load->view('template', $data);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The top of the `file_path` is in your document root. If you need to access a file inside `application/views` write:

```
$path = APPPATH . "views/textiles/about.txt";
$data['file_contents'] = $this->load->file($path, true);
$this->load->view('your_view', $data);
```

It's best to use `APPPATH` as shown, in case you ever decide to change your directory structure and reroute it in `index.php`. Note, if you're on a *NIX box, you'll need to grant the appropriate permissions to this directory/file.

Then in your view, you would access the file simply using `$file_contents`.

Comment: Why the cowardly downvote? I just tested this and it **works**.

Comment: @JordanArseno  That was me, I apologize since I misread part of your answer at first.  However I cannot undo the downvote now that he has accepted your answer, again my apologies.

Comment: In such an anonymous upvote/downvote world, it takes courageousness to confess. Heroic. I salute you, cheers @WillSampson

Answer (score 0):

```
    $this->load->file('application/views/textiles/about.txt',true);
```

get rid of the ../ at the beginning of the file location. See codeigniter documentation on this.